# Refresh Listview javafx with attached listener in javafx

Tags: java, listview, javafx-8

I have a list view that is populated by an observable Array list. My steps are the following

1. Populate observable array list
2. Populate list view using listView.setItems() method
3. set custom cell using listView.setCellFactory(),
4. Attach listener for list view.

More particularly attachListener happens this way

```
private void attachListViewListener() {
   testServersListView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((ObservableValue <? extends TestserverInformation> ov, TestserverInformation oldValue, TestserverInformation newValue )->{
        this.selectedInfo = testServersListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        updateTabs();
    });

}
```

I want to be able to refesh the list by pushing a button. The methods are the following

```
@FXML
public void btnRefreshServerListClicked(){
    log.info("Refreshing list");
    testServersListView.getItems().clear();
    fillObservableTestserverInfoList();        
    testServersListView.setItems(observableTestserverInfoList);
    selectAndUpdate(); //selects the first element on the list
}
```

The problem is that when I clear the list items selectedInfo variable is set to null and the Listener is tiggered, causing a nullpointerexception (because selectAndUpdate uses selectedInfo for updating it's controls. Can I remove the listener without having to set it as a different variable e.g?

```
private myListener = new ChangeListener<...>(){
};
```

Comment: How the selectAndUpdate() looks like? If it is really selecting the first element in the list, then selectedInfo should never be null for it.

Comment: You may put a null check in the listener: if(newValue !=null) {  selectedInfo=newValue; updateTabs();  } . But it may break your logic. Since the selectedInfo stays with old value then, when there is no selection in the list (i.e. newValue == null).